# Can retransmitted TCP segment with lower sequence number have higher acknowledgment?

Tags: tcp

In TCP,

segment1---client-to-server----x(dropped)

seg1(ACK+somedata)<-----------server-to-client

segment2---------->client-to-server

seg2(ack+somedata)<-----------server-to-client

Retransmitted Segment1------> client-to-server

Now can retransmitted segment1 ack for seg2? Or seg2 will be acked by seperate message from client?

Comment: The ACK sequence number is the number of the last byte that has been correctly received along with all its predecessors. The retransmitted segment 1 should ACK the last byte that the sender has correctly received up to, and the server should ACK the last sequence number of segment 2 when they have both arrived. Your example isn't very clear. All transmissions in TCP are segments, not packets, and I don't  know what `packet1` would even be, unless it was the ACK for a segment before `segment1`, in which case `packet2` would be identical.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question now. And used "segment" keyword everywhere. 

So retransmitted segment1 will send next expected seqn.

Comment: Answer is the same.